# How to prevent `docker image prune -f -a` from deleting intermediary images being used in an ongoing build?

Tags: docker, docker-image, docker-build

I have couple of dangled and unused docker images.

I am deleting them using `docker prune image -f -a` using a scheduled job.

Sometimes the job runs when a build is running and using one of the intermediary layers belonging to the dangled or unused image. This causes the build process to redo the intermediary images.

How to prevent `docker image prune -f -a` from deleting intermediary images being used in an ongoing build?

Comment: I see your last 4 questions are related to this - wouldn't it be easier to schedule cleanup when no builds area expected?

Comment: Yes just checking if there is known solution given that the world is moving towards parallel builds. Your suggestion is good and the last resort. But the hard disk can get full if I wait to clean up untill time when no builds are expected. For example: I have around 100 builds over period of 8 hours.